# Why does setting variables from page items break my Web worker?

Tags: javascript, html, web-worker

I have a web worker that runs fine, until I try and set one of the parameters I'm passing to it. The code is:

```
//global variables
var xRange = [-2.5, 1];

function startWorker() {
    if(typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
        if(typeof(w) == "undefined") {
            //xRange[0] = document.getElementById("xRange0").value;
            //xRange[1] = document.getElementById("xRange1").value;
            w = new Worker("myWorker.js");
            w.postMessage({ "args": [xRange[0], xRange[1]] });
        }
        w.onmessage = function(event) {
          //Do something.
        };
    } else {
        //no ww support
    }
}
```

If I un-comment the xRange[1] variable, the application runs as expected. However, if I un-comment the xRange[0] variable, the application does not produce expected results.

I checked that the items on the HTML page have the correct ID's.
I used `alert(xRange[0]);` after setting the array, and it confirmed that the value is whatever is inputted into the HTML page item.

I'm at a complete loss as to why one of these lines works, and the other does not.

Here's a fiddle with my source, so you can verify the item ID's are correct: http://jsfiddle.net/cxhrbf10/

One other thing that I've noticed, is that if I try to set more variables from page items in this location, the generation of the image goes from about 200ms to about 800ms. Just wondering why there was such a big performance hit just for accessing page item values.

Thanks!

Comment: "If I un-comment the xRange[1] variable, the application runs as expected." .. well, what are the *actual* values that are passed in that case? Why does the web worker code fail when using *those values*? It would expect that it is either `undefined` or a string like `"12.34"` which causes the problems. Make sure to create different posts for different questions.

Comment: They're the same values. The point of setting them from the page items is to enable users to change them. The initial value of xRange[1] is 1, and the page item starts with the value 1. xRange[0] starts at -2.5 and the page item is set to the same.
As I mentioned, alerting the value of the variable after setting it from the page item returns the expected value of -2.5. I considered the possibility of it returning a string due to the negative, but there's another value I'm setting in the exact same way that has a negative, and it works correctly. Very confused.

Comment: They are *not* the same values as that would result in the same behavior (or it could always be that the very cause of the problem is being misidentified). Verify the values again: "12.34" might look like 12.34, but it is a different value.

Comment: Nope, *not* the same value. Just verified. Use the debugger and/or console.dir (or console.log in Chrome).

Comment: Interesting. They're all being passed in as strings, but it appears that javascript is smart enough to handle the conversion, except when it has a - at the start. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It depends on the operation immediately applied. Some operations will perform numeric conversions (depending upon one or both operands); others will not. And some operations may appear to work although they do not. Always explicitly coerce values to numbers. A fast way is to use `+expr`.

Comment: Any idea on why setting variables from page items causes such a performance hit? Is there just a large overhead associated with using getElementById?

Comment: getElementById should be considered a *fast* / well-optimized operation overall: the problem lies elsewhere. (Although I cannot run the web-worker nor did I notice any slowdown.)

Comment: @user2864740 please add your comments as an answer if this resolves the question.